# JavaScript not printing out values

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to print all values of x,y,z from this equation x − 2y + 3z = 0 (value of  between 1-5, the value of y is between 6-10, and z is between 3-7) on HTML through javascript but the

```
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = x,y,z;
```

Only displays the maximum value of x, y, z. instead of any possible solution. So I'm unsure whether there is a problem with the for loops and the way I'm trying to display on the HTML page. [This is the output I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrtIA.png)

```js
function Solve() {
    {
        var x = [];
        var y = [];
        var z = [];
        var ans = [];
        // x-2y+3z=0
        // x3[1,5] y3[6,10] z3[3,7]
        console.log("x\ty\tz\n\n");
        for (x = 1; x <= 5; x++) {
            for (y = 6; y <= 10; y++) {
                z = (2 * y - x) / 3.0;
                if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0) {
                    if (x % 1 == 0 && y % 1 == 0 && z % 1 == 0) {
                        if (x >= 1 && x <= 5 && y >= 6 && y <= 10 && z >= 3 && z <= 7) {
                            (document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = x), y, z;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (y = 6; y <= 10; y++) {
            for (z = 3; z <= 7; z++) {
                x = 2 * y - 3 * z;
                if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0) {
                    if (x % 1 == 0 && y % 1 == 0 && z % 1 == 0) {
                        if (x >= 1 && x <= 5 && y >= 6 && y <= 10 && z >= 3 && z <= 7) {
                            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = y;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (z = 3; z <= 7; z++) {
            for (x = 1; x <= 5; x++) {
                y = (x + 3 * z) / 3.0;
                if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0) {
                    if (x % 1 == 0 && y % 1 == 0 && z % 1 == 0) {
                        if (x >= 1 && x <= 5 && y >= 6 && y <= 10 && z >= 3 && z <= 7) {
                            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = z;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<center>
    <p>x - 2y + 3z = 0</p>
    <button onclick="Solve()">Solve</button><br />

    <span id="display"></span>

    <span id="display"></span>
    <span id="display"></span>
    <span id="display"></span>
    <span id="display"></span>
    <span id="display"></span>
    <span id="display"></span>
    <span id="display"></span>
    <span id="display"></span>
    <span id="display"></span>
</center>
```

Comment: attribute **id** in the span tag must be **unique** for each tag. use the class.

Comment: so am I supposed to put 3 tags and 3 ids in total?

Comment: What would a statement like `(document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = x), y, z;` mean?

Comment: I assume it's supposed to print out the values of x,y,z like how it's in the desired output(image)

Comment: @ChenukaJayasuriya, first, redo it as `<span class="display"></span>` for all span tag, and use `getElementsByClassName()` or `querySelectorAll()` to refer to the class.

Comment: in that case, I get no output at all @s.kuznetsov

Comment: Please don't use the `<center>` it's deprecated; `var` and `innerHTML` could damage your application avoid them too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following code to print the solutions for the equation:

html:

```
<center>
    <p>x - 2y + 3z = 0</p>
    <button onclick="Solve()">Solve</button><br />
    <div id="solution" style="color: green"></div>
</center>
```

javascript :

```
function Solve()
{
    const solutions=[];
    for(let x=1;x<=5;x++)
        for(let y=6;y<=10;y++)
            for(let z=3;z<=7;z++)
                if (x-2*y+3*z==0)
                    solutions.push([x,y,z]);
                    
   var solutionElement = document.getElementById("solution");
   solutionElement.innerText  = "The solutions are:"
   solutions.forEach(solution => {
   const node = document.createElement("div");
   node.innerText = `x= ${solution[0]}, y=${solution[1]}, z=${solution[2]}`;
   solutionElement.appendChild(node);
   });
}
```

PS: You can apply style however you want.

Comment: could you explain to me the code at the bottom?

Comment: This equation has more than one solutions. So in the code above we have calculated all the solutions and stored in the array named 'solutions'. Next part is to render this solutions on UI/HTML. We have added one div with id as 'solution'. we are creating and appending child nodes with solution details to main div (id = solution) nodes. Since we are using solutions array to create and append child dev, number of child nodes created are same as number of solutions we have.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be OP's objective to list all integer solutions for the given equation in a given range for x, y and z. The following will deliver that solution:

```js
// x-2y+3z=0
// x3[1,5] y3[6,10] z3[3,7]
const res=[];
for(let x=1;x<=5;x++)
 for(let y=6;y<=10;y++)
   for(let z=3;z<=7;z++)
    if (x-2*y+3*z==0)
     res.push([x,y,z]);
document.querySelector("tbody").innerHTML=res.map(r=>`<tr><tr><td>${r.join("</td><td>")}</td></tr>`).join("");
```

```css
th,td {text-align:right; width:20px;padding: 0 6px} 
.centered {text-align: center}
table {margin: 0 auto}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
<p>x - 2y + 3z = 0</p>
<table><thead><tr><th>x</th><th>y</th><th>z</th></tr></thead>
<tbody></tbody></table>
</div>
```